# Left Join in hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I am trying to run below hibernate query. But it is throwing me an error as "
org.hibernate.QueryException: outer or full join must be followed by path expression"

Can somebody tell me what is wrong in this query?

```
select P from Package P left join PkgBid PB 
where P.pid = PB.pid 
and P.bemsid = 2148862 
and P.packagestatus= 1 
and PB.pid is null 
order by P.pid
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an `on` clause for your join.  The exact syntax depends on your implementation, but is probably something like:

```
select P.*
from Package P
left join PkgBid PB 
    on P.pid = PB.pid 
where P.bemsid = 2148862 
and P.packagestatus = 1 
and PB.pid is null 
order by P.pid
```